UDP routing through VPS to local machine for server hosting
I am hosting a Minecraft server using geyser to allow both bedrock and java players to join my server. Java compatibility was easy, I set up a ssh tunnel from Local to VPS and all worked well, however bedrock uses UDP. The specifics are less important than the fact that I need to receive and send UDP from my local system as if it were directly connected to the bedrock clients.
Here is the current network I have set up, I am only able to control my local system and VPS
‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ [Local System Hosting MCS]
‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎⇅
‎ ‎ ‎ ‎‎[My router (I have no controll over)]
‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎⇅
‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ [VPS as public facing router]
‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎⇅
‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ [Multiple Minecraft Clients]
The closest to working I got was using Socat to pipe UDP through a separate ssh tunnel and then Socat them back to UDP on the client side ex:
On client:
socat tcp-l:(ssh tunnel port),fork,reuseaddr udp:127.0.0.1:25565  

On server:
socat udp-l:(public udp port),fork,reuseaddr tcp:127.0.0.1:(ssh tunnel port)   

Among other issues this is not bidirectional so I attempted to use iptables/netsh forwarding to get to opposite flow but with very inconsistent results. I used the following rule on client and visa versa on server
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=25565 listenaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=(ssh tunnel port) connectaddress=127.0.0.1

I have tried many many other ways (Dante, Openvpn, + more) of forwarding UDP traffic to and from my VPS router to no avail, most likely due to a misunderstanding I have about what is required to forward the UDP traffic.
The main question is how does one go about forwarding UDP traffic given these constraints
